# Config transformation with Webdeploy, Preview not working

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, csproj, build-definition, config-transformation

I want to use config transformation for custom files, if I replace `???` with `MSDeployPublish`, the `Preview` functionality is not working and it replaces the local files in solution. However the publish works without using `Preview` keeping local files untouched.

Config files:

```
AppSettings.config  
└AppSettings.Test.config  
└AppSettings.Stage.config  
└AppSettings.Release.config  
ConnectionString.config  
└ConnectionString.Test.config  
└ConnectionString.Stage.config  
└ConnectionString.Release.config
```

What is the correct name of the target to use transformation for preview (without changing the files in soulution)? The way that `web.config` works when making preview with webDeploy

```xml
<Target Name="???">
   <TransformXml Source="App_Config\AppSettings.config" Destination="App_Config\AppSettings.config" Transform="App_Config\AppSettings.$(Configuration).config" />
    <TransformXml Source="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" Destination="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" Transform="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.$(Configuration).config" />
</Target>
```

I don't want to use any extensions like SlowCheetah, just build in functionalities.

`<Target Name="Build">` also works

#### UPDATE 1

I've succeeded to publish without change local config files:

`Destination="$(_PackageTempDir)\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config"`

But the Preview still not transforming the configs (also when I define a message for output it is not appear). What black magic happens when I click "Preview", in the publish screen ?

I've tried with targets: `TransformWebConfigCore`,`CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage` ,`GatherAllFilesToPublish`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it.

The Target name should be a custom name that doesn't exist. Then `AfterTargets` attribute should be specified with value of **`Package`**. This target happens almost at the end of the chain and ensures that the `$(_PackageTempDir)` directory is created.

The transformations are done in the package directory. This way ensures when making a preview with webdeploy it will compare files correctly and without change local files in source control.

Here is the definition:

```xml
<Target Name="CustomConfigTransform" AfterTargets="Package">
  <TransformXml Source="App_Config\AppSettings.config" Destination="$(_PackageTempDir)\App_Config\AppSettings.config" Transform="App_Config\AppSettings.$(Configuration).config" />
  <TransformXml Source="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" Destination="$(_PackageTempDir)\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" Transform="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.$(Configuration).config" />
</Target>
```

Of course there could be a better way: in the target `CollectWebConfigsToTransform` from `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`, it should know somehow that there are more config files for transform. But currently no idea.

Comment: Another approach that could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381408/6142097